# Marking specific point on highchart column

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am working to create highchart for a marketing team, please check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyotipuri/kh5jY/5124/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          events: {
            load: function () {
              Highcharts.updateMarketMarkers(this);
            },
            redraw: function () {
              Highcharts.updateMarketMarkers(this);
            }
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        xAxis: [
          {
            categories: ['North','South','East', 'West']
          }
        ],
        yAxis: [
          {
            title: null,
            labels: {enabled: false},
            stackLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
              }
            }
          },
          {
            title: null,
            labels: {enabled: false}
          }
        ],
        tooltip: false,
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            pointPadding: 0,
            borderWidth: 0
          },
          series: {
            point: {
              events: {
                click: function () {
                  $scope.drillChart(this.category);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Jan',
            data: [23, 45, 24, 30],
            type: 'column'
          },
          {
            name: 'Feb',
            data: [50, 40, 25, 10],
            type: 'column'
          }
        ]
      });
});
```

The columns here show sales in various regions, I need to be able to mark out specific point on the columns that will be sales target and it will show is sales met the target. The marking has to be done for both columns (Jan, Feb) for all 4 regions (NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you mark out that points? I think you can achieve that in two ways:

- using column series with `low` options (or `columnrange` series): http://jsfiddle.net/kh5jY/5132/
- using scatter just to put marker on such point: http://jsfiddle.net/kh5jY/5133/

  ```
  {
      name: 'South target',
      data: [20, 20, 20, 20],
      zIndex: 10,
      pointPlacement: 0.15,
      type: 'scatter'
  }, {
      name: 'North target',
      data: [20, 20, 20, 20],
      zIndex: 10,
      pointPlacement: -0.15,
      type: 'scatter'
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi Pawel, I have used your option 1 with low in my graph. But there is one issue. The number of points in my graph can vary from 2 - 200 and number of columns can also vary from 3 - 30. And in extreme situations the marker points distort from main column. Can you please suggest something to fix this.

Comment: Could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Thanks. Or just use scatter solution.